# iPhone - access XAMPP server (localhost) on my mac in the same network

Tags: iphone, xampp

I want to create an iPhone app which makes calls to a web service. For testing, I want to first create the API calls on my mac (server running XAMPP) and if it works fine there I want to port it to the actual server.

If my iPhone and mac are on the same network, can I access the web service using the IP address of my mac?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any time someone answers with "why not," ignore the post.  This just takes up space and adds absolutely no value...their post imitating their life.

Anyway, I access my laptop localhost (WAMP stack) from my iPod Touch by entering the IP address of my laptop on my Touch location bar.  There is some configuration that needs to happen for this to work.  I found what I needed at:

http://www.frihost.com/forums/vt-88381.html

Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

I can not speak about actual development, however I access intranet pages from a Ipod Touch all the time by either typing http ://ip or http://local_dns_name

As long as the iphone / ipod is on the network correctly (e.g. through standard wifi and not 3g/whatever) you should be able to access any and all local resources.

Answer (score 0):

What I do:

Connected to the same network, I go in to the wireless settings and create a manual proxy that points to my machine. I use Charles proxy for testing a lot/seeing traffic, works like a charm and it lets me use my macbook hosts file so I don't need to do any funky listening rules in apache - just the same vhost settings I use on my machine already.

http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/faqs/using-charles-from-an-iphone/

Answer (score -3):

Why not?

Have you tried it and have some problems?

Comment: Yes. I did try but keep getting an error that the address does not exist. I have XAMPP running on the system, the system and device are on the same wifi n/w

Comment: Have you tried accesing that XAMPP from another machine connected in the same interface. Is it a exclusive problem of iPhone?